# The current path, search_shop/5ka/, didn't match any of these. Django

Tags: python, django

I have an error:

> The current path, search_shop/5ka/, didn't match any of these.

Reason of the problem is name of the slug field `5ka`. When I changed name from `5ka` to `pka` it works fine.

How can I use `5ka` without errors?

**models.py**

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=False, default="Shop") # I mean this field

def get_search_url(self):
    return reverse('search_shop', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomePageView.as_view(), name='main_list'),
    path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
    path('search_shop/<slug:slug>', ProductListView.as_view(), name='search_shop'),
    path('search_shop_results/<slug:slug>/', ProductSearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_shop_results'),
    path('<slug:slug>/<int:pk>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),

    path('shops/', ShopListView.as_view(), name='shop_list'),
]
```

**shop_list.html**

```
{% for shop in shops %}   
    <a href="{{ shop.get_search_url }}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just include a `/` in the following line it will be resolved

```
path('search_shop/<slug:slug>/', ProductListView.as_view(), name='search_shop'),
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps me!

Comment: just remember to put slash at the end while passing arguments in the url